# Last char on string doesnt leap in setter in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Im really lost now. I have form, which is developed for checking SPZ from OCR reader. I have few conditions in my textbox. These conditions enabling/disabling another buttons and radio buttons. In Some records it works very well. But in some, i have interesting problem. I got this piece of code:

```
// Loading can be if:  
// SPZ Ocr is different
// SPZ Notified is OK
// SPZ Final (real) OK
// SPZ notified == real, but its different from OCR: then i can enable button continue loading. When i click, then i can detail window activate.                   
else if (_licencePlate != PlateInformation.LicencePlateOCR && _licencePlate == PlateInformation.LicencePlateNotified)
{
    CheckedWaitState = false;
    CanEnableButton = true;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEnableButton");
    ConfirmCheckSPZ = false;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("ConfirmCheckSPZ");
    CheckWaitStateEnable = false;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("CheckWaitStateEnable");
    CheckReturnStateEnable = false;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("CheckReturnStateEnable");
    NotifyPropertyChanged("LicencePlate");
}
```

If i writing some SPZ in this particular textbox, its leap in this conditions wells. But only last char of string not. The previous chars leaps fine. Any ideas why? And of course when this last char doesnt leap into conditions, then nothing is activate.

There is a xaml piece of code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtCheckSpz" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="63,10,0,0" Text="{Binding LicencePlate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource NormalTextBox1}" Width="128" Height="33" >
```

Comment: What does SPZ mean? When you write "leap in" do you mean that the conditional code is (not) executed? It seems english is not your first language - thats ok, but we still need to clarify what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In a TwoWay binding with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged every character typed (or deleted) in the TextBox will trigger a set of the target property, in your case 'LicencePlate'.
In the set of this property you can call additional code which will change whatever state you need after analyzing the received value.
For example:

```
private string m_LicencePlate
public string LicencePlate
{
     get { return m_LicencePlate; }
     set 
     {
        if (value == m_LicencePlate) return;
        m_LicencePlate = value;
        UpdateStateAfterLicensePlateChange();
     }
}
```